# doing .length on json array returns undefined

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I have following json encoded array coming from ajax call

```
{"country":{"0":"United States of America","United States of America":{"states":{"0":"Alaska","Alaska":{"cities":["Adak","Akiachak","Akiak","Akutan","Alakanuk"]}}}}}
```

Following is my ajax code

```
$.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   url: "test.php",
   data: "action=2",
   cache: 'false',
   success: function(abcd){
     alert(abcd);
     var obj = new Array();
     var obj = $.parseJSON(abcd);
     alert(obj.country.length);
   }
});
```

When i try using `obj.country[0]` it returns "United States of America". But when i try to get the length of the array using `obj.country.length` it returns `undefined`.

I have browsed a couple of posts and only difference i could see was use of dataType: json and using `header()` to define content type to json on .php page. I have tried both methods but that didn't work out either. And on .php page i have declared following as array:

```
$data = array();
$data['country'] = array();
$data['country']['United States of America'] = array();
$data['country']['United States of America']['states'] = array();
$data['country']['United States of America']['states']['Alaska']['cities'] = array();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `obj.country` isn't an array, but an object.

An object is enclosed in curly braces (`{}`) and an array in square ones (`[]`). See http://json.org/ for more information.

In your example content, `"cities":["Adak","Akiachak","Akiak","Akutan","Alakanuk"]` would be an array, which you can call with `obj["country"]["United States of America"]["states"]["Alaska"]["cities"]`.

---

So, judging from your example this would work:

```
$us['name'] = "United";
$alaska['name'] = "Alaska";
$alaska['cities'] = array("city1", "city2");
$us['states'] = array($alaska)
$data = array($us);
```

I expect it would render like `[{"name": "United", "states": [{"name":"Alaska", "cities": ["city1","city2"]}]}]`.

I'm sure it could be done better or more compact though, I don't have much experience with PHP in this regard.

Comment: Ok so how do I convert it to any array?

Comment: You might want to add, that `obj.country[0]` actually returns a value, because there is an attribute called `0` within said object.

Comment: @SaadBashir If you can't change the source of the content, you will have to loop through the object and add every entry into a new array.

Comment: I can change the source of the content. But like I said I am already defining it as an array like I explained in the question. At every stage I have defined it as an array. I don't know what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: @SaadBashir: In you PHP code you are overwritting the array definition with every assignment. If you encode it as JSON it will be an object, because Javascript does not know hashed arrays.

Comment: So should I just defined $data = array and not do the same for any later?

Comment: @SaadBashir: It is still unclear as what you are trying to accomplish. You only described what is happening, but not what you are expecting.

Comment: @SaadBashir By doing `$data['country']['United States of America'] = array();`, you are making "country" an object with a key called 'United States of America', whose value is an array.

Comment: I want an array which has Countries->States->(Cities of that particular State)

Comment: @SaadBashir: I am out. You are either not able to describe your requirements or you are unaware of array behaviour in Javascript. Maybe you should look into how arrays work in Javascript first.

Comment: I need to create a multidimensional array. I get your point that currently I have converted countries and other items into objects by declaring them as array(). So I would appreciate if you could explain how can I create a multidimensional array here with the same format as described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

`alert((Object.keys(obj.country) || []).length);`

Comment: What about that? Add more information to your answer. What are you trying to accomplish with that? How is that helping OP?

Comment: Well yes this returns 2.